# Is the statement $(\forall x)(\exists y)x\gt 1\implies y^2 + 2y = x$ true if the variables $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ Why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Is the statement $(\forall x)(\exists y)x > 1 \implies y^2 + 2y = x$ true if the variables $x,y\in\mathbb Q$? Why?

How do I find out if the statement is true? I am not sure which definition to use.

Comment: Note that $y^2+2y=x$ is equivalent to $(y+1)^2=x+1$. Therefore, $x+1$ would have to be the square of a rational number. If you choose $x>1$  such that $x+1$ is not a square of a rational then there is no such $y$. We could take, for example, $x=\frac{3}{2}$. Then $x+1=\frac{5}{2}$. Have you seen the proof that $2$ is not a square of a rational number? The same idea works to prove that $5/2$ is not a square.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement begins "for all $x$". Then it has an implication with $x>1$ as the assumption. And then later has the clause requiring $x$ to be in $\mathbb{Q}$. It's confusing to read all of that, and if I understand the intent, it is equivalent to:$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}_{>1})(\exists y\in\mathbb{Q})\text{ such that }y^2+2y=x$$
Now if that is correct, then the statement is false. For example, $x$ could be $2$. Then the real solutions for $y$ are $-1\pm\sqrt{3}$, which are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. So no such $y$ exists.